# [Linux]Load .so file for JNI results in: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libdebug in java.library.path

Tags: java, c++, linux, java-native-interface

I need some native C++ code to be called within my Java application so I use 'System.loadLibrary(String)' to load the required .so file, but when I try to execute the Java application from Eclipse I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libdebug in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at org.server.util.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:5)
    at org.server.Server.main(Server.java:18)
```

The library path property setting is:

```
java.library.path="/home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/client:/home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386"
```

And I placed libdebug.so in /home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/.
The .so file was compiled like this:

```
g++ -I /home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/include 
    -I /home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/include/linux -fPIC -c debug.cpp 
    -o /home/benjamin/workspace/server/bin/linux-x86/debug.o
```

And linked like this:

```
ld -shared -soname Debug.so.1 -o Debug.so.1.0 -lc debug.o
```

Comment: If you manually run with `java -Djava.library.path=/home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/ org.server.Server`, do you still get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`?

Comment: Yes I do. riijgjweg (<-- sorry had to meet minimum character limit :O)

Comment: What if you switch to `System.load("/home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/libdebug.so")`? Does that work?

Comment: Nope. That'll just tell me that a directory separator should not appear in a library name. And it still throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: It sounds like you're still using `loadLibrary`. Does `load` work?

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/libdebug.so: /home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/libdebug.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_ this is the error message I get when I substitute 'loadLibrary' with: System.load("/home/benjamin/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/libdebug.so");

Answer (score 3):

If you call `System.loadLibrary("foo")` then the JVM will look for a shared library called `libfoo.so` on Unix and `foo.dll` on Windows.

You are calling your shared library `Debug.so.1.0` according to that link line.

Try renaming your library to `libDebug.so` (or making a symlink from `Debug.so.1.0` to `libDebug.so`) and then changing the source code line to `System.loadLibrary("Debug");` and tell us what happens.